# How to remove the all child classes from the parent in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to remove the bootstrap child classes row from the parent element .But not working for me showing the errors.

the code is

```
 if(document.getElementById(v)){
        console.log(v)
        document.getElementById("mapper").removeChild(document.getElementsByClassName("row"))
       //document.getElementById("mapper").classList.remove('row');
     

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering element with id="mapper" is your parent element and you want to remove children's row class. Try this :

```
var mapper = document.getElementById("mapper").children;
for(i=0; i<mapper.length;i++) {
   mapper[i].classList.remove("row")
}
```

Comment: Add some more code. So, that I can understand which is your parent element. It seems confusing as you are trying to get element with id v and mapper both.